# Анимация WPF. Как сослаться на другой элемент в Storyboard.TargetName?

Tags: wpf, анимация

Пытаюсь сделать анимацию элементов пользовательского интерфейса, запускаемую с помощью триггеров WPF, но не могу понять как сослаться на другой элемент.

Нижеприведенный код выдает ошибку:

> "Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName 'Button123' ".

```
<Button x:Name="Button123" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >123</Button>

<Button Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" > 222             
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard TargetProperty="Width" TargetName="Button123">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="150"
                                 AutoReverse="True"
                                 RepeatBehavior="0:0:10"
                                 Duration="0:0:3"
                                />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Спасибо Vadim Ovchinnikov за помощь. Отличный вариант. Я нашел еще один способ решения проблемы: [еще один вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737367/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо переместить ваш код в `Button.Triggers` из `Style.Triggers`. Тем более это сильно упростит ваш код

```
<Button x:Name="Button123" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >123</Button>

<Button Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >222
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Width" TargetName="Button123">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="150"
                             AutoReverse="True"
                             RepeatBehavior="0:0:10"
                             Duration="0:0:3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. У меня попутный вопрос (возможно наивный) - почему в Style я не вижу других элементов? Просто хочется разобраться в этой возникшей проблеме до конца.

Comment: @andreyLv Как я понимаю, это не значит, что элементов "не видно". Это значит, что нельзя задавать анимацию в стилях для других элементов, так как вы можете же задавать стили и снаружи, в других файлах, в зависимости от темы, применяя наследование и т. д. Я не уверен на 100%, чем именно вызвано это ограничение, но полагаю, что это сделано для того, чтобы предотвращать странное поведение, когда в стилях одних элементов можно добавлять анимацию других. По умолчанию (без указания `TargetName`) анимация применяется к самому элементу, а это задавать в стилях всё-таки допустимо.

Comment: @andreyLv Мой вопрос решил вашу проблему? Если да, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый, если нет, то напишите комментарий, что именно вам не подходит.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, все подошло. Забыл просто отметить =)